# How to inject a property from properties file to a non-managed class in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I would like to set a property to a class that is not managed by Spring. The actual case is as follows: I have a regex which I want to externalize to the properties file. So far what I have tried is to create a `CommandLineRunner`, and read from properties file and set the regex to whatever field I want. But I wonder if there's an out of the box way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do one of the following:

1. Make the class a "normal" Java class where the regex is passed in via constructor or method parameter by the Spring managed class who uses it.
2. Give the class a static field "regex" (with a default value perhaps) that gets set by a Spring bean via a setter on startup (`@PostConstruct`).
3. Give the class a static field "regex" (with a default value perhaps) that gets set using a `static` block in your class reading from the properties file (if it is available on the classpath!).
4. Make the class a "normal" Singleton (with default values perhaps) that gets initialized on Spring startup (https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)

Comment: thanks for your response. I liked 2. one. One question tho. Is there any difference between 1. and what I have already tried? Plus, why would any of these be a better choice than what I have already done? I am just curious.

Comment: Only minor differences in the technical way of doing things I guess, but not major differences.
I personally like 1 the most because I personally like to have classes initialized via constructor without any additional doing.